# Nested loop returning limit

Tags: javascript, function, loops

I am working on a quiz for an online course.

> For this quiz, you're going to create a function called buildTriangle() that will accept an input (the triangle at its widest width) and will return the string representation of a triangle. See the example output below.

> ```
> buildTriangle(10);
>
> returns
> * 
> * * 
> * * * 
> * * * * 
> * * * * * 
> * * * * * * 
> * * * * * * * 
> * * * * * * * * 
> * * * * * * * * * 
> * * * * * * * * * *
> ```

I solved it using this function:

```
function buildTriangle(length) {
    var line = "";
    var triangle ="";
    for (h = 1; h <= length; h++) {
        makeLine(length);
        function makeLine(length) {line += "* ";}
        triangle += line + "\n";
    }
    return triangle
}

buildTriangle(10));
```

Which successfully returns:

```
* 
* * 
* * * 
* * * * 
* * * * * 
* * * * * * 
* * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * *
```

However, before getting to this solution, I tried this:

```
function buildTriangle(length) {
    var line = "";
    var triangle ="";
    for (h = 1; h <= length; h++) {
        makeLine(length);
        function makeLine(length) {
            for (i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
                line += "* ";
            }
        }
        triangle += line + "\n" 
    }
    return triangle
}

console.log(buildTriangle(10));
```

Which returned this:

```
* * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
* * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
```

Why does this nested `makeLine` function not go through the loop normally (i.e. starting at 1), but instead produce 10 every time? Is there a way to force the loop to run normally (1, 2, 3, 4, 5...)? Why does this nesting not work?

Answer (score 3):

Because you have a loop in `makeLine` which is looping from 1 through `length` (inclusive), and you're using `+=` when adding to line. So the `line` is going to get `"* "` added to it `length` times, each time you call `makeLine`.

---

Side note: There's no reason to have the `makeLine` function at all. But if you're going to have it, don't declare it within the `for`. That used to be invalid (though browser JavaScript engines tolerated it in some cases). It's no longer invalid, but there's no good reason for it here.

Side note 2: Your code is falling prey to what I call [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). You need to declare your `h` (and `i`) variables.

Comment: Got it. It was going through the makeLine loop entirely. So best solutions are:

function buildTriangle(length) {
    var line = "";
    var triangle ="";
    for (var h = 1; h <= length; h++) {
        line += "* ";
        triangle += line + "\n";
    }
    return triangle
}

Or alternatively two functions:

var line = "";
var triangle ="";

function makeLine(h) {line += "* ";}

function buildTriangle(length) {
    for (var h = 1; h <= length; h++) {
        makeLine(h);
        triangle += line + "\n"
    } 
    return triangle
}

Is that right? Thank you!

Comment: @CarloTapia - Sounds right. I mean, there are lots of ways to spin it, but that seems fine. :-)

Answer (score 1):

### Issue 1

The first issue with your second function is that you are passing `length` into `makeLine` instead of `h`:

```js
function buildTriangle(length) {
    var line = "";
    var triangle ="";
    for (h = 1; h <= length; h++) {
        makeLine(h);
        function makeLine(length) {
            for (i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
                line += "* ";
            }
        }
        triangle += line + "\n" 
    }
    return triangle
}

console.log(buildTriangle(10));
```

### Issue 2

Next, you will notice that the triangle is adding `h` extra than need be. That's because you have `line` set to concatenate and not clear after each run:

```js
function buildTriangle(length) {
    var line = "";
    var triangle ="";
    for (h = 1; h <= length; h++) {
        makeLine(h);
        function makeLine(length) {
            line = "";
            for (i = 1; i <= length; i++) {
                line += "* ";
            }
        }
        triangle += line + "\n" 
    }
    return triangle
}

console.log(buildTriangle(10));
```

Presto! Fixed the issue and it should now be running as expected!

Answer (score 0):

The inner and outer loop conditions are checking against `length` which is 10, so you get 10 *s every time the inner loop runs. To get the intended result you can compare `i` to `h` instead of `length`.

Also, it is a bad idea to redeclare the function inside of each iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your `makeline` inner function should not take `length` as parameter since `length` is the widest with of the triangle. Instead, `makeline` has to use the exact width to print at that instance. And in this case, your `h`. Otherwise, your makeline will print `length*length` lines at the end.